# Email in Java Webapps, A Better Way?

Tags: java, spring, email, web-applications

I'm renovating a legacy Java Servlet webapp.   I'm wondering there is a better way to do email.  Right now the app has a giant class for it where most of the verbiage is about concatenating message text with data and the conditions for deciding to do so.

I'm using Spring-MVC is  newer parts of the application.  I did a quick Google on Spring and Email and it looks like Spring is mostly about abstracting the sending of email itself which I don't have a problem with.  Am I correct?

What I would like is an API/system that will allow me to put message text for individual emails into text files and allow me to insert data into that text via variables.  I would also like something that will make the collection of that data and the calculation of conditionals less unwieldy.

Lastly, the app only has about 6 different emails that it sends.  I'm looking for system that is QUICK to learn.  I don't need to conquer the email world, I would just like to clean up some messy legacy code.

Is there such a quick to learn email api?

Thanks much in advance for any info

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring to compose email messages (see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mail.html), and you can use plain text files with tokens (maybe Apache-style, like ${foo.bar}) and read them in, replace the tokens in code, and set that text to your email message text.  As others have suggested you can use a template engine to do that, or you can just use `String.replaceAll()`.

Comment: Looks like a small scale simple approach for my small scale problem and I like that it uses Spring, something Im already invested in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a templating system like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

From my experience of both I would suggest that Velocity is a little bit simpler, but Freemarker is more powerful. Perhaps you should abstract your choice out and substitute later as required.

Answer (score 1):

For message contents I think a template engine may work for you. Check out [Google Soy](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/) or [Freemarker](http://www.freemarker.org/).